# iOS UnitTesting Dependence

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I am writing unit test to test my web services calls. Issue is all calls depend on token (which I get after I am logged in). In setup method, I called the login but since it's async call, before the token is set, my test method is called and it got null in token. There are couple of solutions (set an arbitrary token or call login before I test my actual service). I want better solution to handle this thing. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With XCTest you can let tests wait for async calls to return. You can use this to retrieve the token in setUp, and use the token in the tests:

```
class MyTestCase: XCTestCase {

    var token: String?

    override func setUp() {

        if token != nil {

            let expectation = expectationWithDescription("login")
            webService.login { (resultToken) -> Void in
                token = resultToken
                expectation.fulfill()
            }

            // this will wait until expectation is fulfilled or the timeout (30 secs) is exceeded (will trigger error)
            waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: nil)
        }

    }

    func testThatMyFeatureWorks() {
        // here you can use the token
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi there. There is one more requirement. I want to add them in class setup and teardown methods. I believe expectationWithDescription and waitForExpectationsWithTimeout are not class level methods and will not work in Setup and TearDown.

Comment: In my solution the webservice login is only executed once, due to the token != nil check. It's not class level, but the webservice login is only called once for all tests, and the tests keep reusing the token. But if you have strict requirements to use class level setup and teardown my solution won't work.